# Marquee on the same line with image

Tags: html, marquee

I want to put a marquee on "Diversitati transparent" from right to left on the same line with image(like the text from marquee should go into image).

I have this code:

```css
h1 {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #FF0000;
}

h2 {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #FF0000;
}

.header img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
}

.header h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  left: 140px;
}

.header h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="sigla.jpg" alt="logo" />
  <body bgcolor="lightblue">
    <center>
      <h1>Diversitati transparente</h1>
    </center>
    <i><h2> Pagina de start </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You HTML is highly invalid.  The body tag is the first tag after the <head> in HTML and cannot live inside other tags - all container start tags have to have end tags in your code and they don't. Where is the marquee?

Comment: Thank you a lot. Yeah, sorry I do not know a lot of html.

Comment: I want to put a marquee on "Diversitati transparent" from right to left on the same line with image(like the text from marquee should go into image).
I said this. I want to put a marquee but I dont know how, to be on the same line with image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Marquee is deprecated
2. Marquees take up 100% with so make narrower
3. I fixed some of your html

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue
}

h1 {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #FF0000;
}

h2 {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #FF0000;
}

.header img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
}

.header h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  left: 140px;
}

.header h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  left: 500px;
}
#imgcontainer { float:left }
marquee { width:80% }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="imgcontainer"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="logo" /></div>
  <marquee>
    <h1>Diversitati transparente</h1>
  </marquee>
  <h2> Pagina de start </h2>
</div>
```